# Angular - FormGroup - setValue Method ignores specific string value

Tags: angular, setvalue

I have very strange problem that I encountered recently. I am trying to set value to form controller in angular

```
this.form.controls['WhateverKeyIS'].setValue('ABC');
```

The above works but if I set different value

```
this.form.controls['WhateverKeyIS'].setValue('B10');
```

or

```
this.form.controls['WhateverKeyIS'].setValue('B05');
```

The controller completely ignores these and does not set value of control, I am assuming the setValue auto converts those B05 into hex code and fails, I could not make any other logical deduction. I have tried everything to make sure I am sending string but it always fails on these values.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

I am using angular 8.

EDIT -

```
@Input() form: FormGroup;
  onSelectOption(item) {
      this.form.controls[this.question.typeVal[0].key].setValue(item.key);
    console.log('select:', this.form.controls);
  }
```

onSelect is called in ui like

```
    <app-bootstrap-dropdown
      [title]="question.typeVal[0].label"
      [placeholder]="'Search '+question.typeVal[0].label"
      [currentItem]="initialValues[question.typeVal[0].key]"
      [collection]="question.typeVal[0].values"
      (selectionEvent)="onSelectOption($event)"
      (removeSelection)="onRemoveSelection()"
      [displayFunc]="getDropdownValue"
    ></app-bootstrap-dropdown>
```

But even if I change item.key with string 'B05 or B10' it still doesn't work.

Comment: if I add space after B10 it does work 'B10 ', so for some reason B10 is not valid value and I have no idea why :/

Comment: What type of control is `WhateverKeyIS` ? input, select, etc

Comment: Can you post the form declaration as well ?

Comment: Can you reproduce this example. I tried reproducing it on StackBlitz but it works.. https://stackblitz.com/edit/form-control-btk5fx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Yes doing it a sec

Comment: I have updated the code with declaration. Could it be angular version? :/ it works for me the link you have provided @AlvinSaldanha

Comment: As I am using Angular 8, my typescript version is  "typescript": "~3.5.3"

Comment: My form is created dynamically by the way as in what fields need to be there is decided at runtime depending on external json file. The only confusing part is it works for other keys and also works if I add Space or something with those 2 keys. :/

Comment: See that if you has `<select name="select" (change)="change($event)">`  in .ts you need asks about `item.target.value`, if you use a template reference variable `<select #myselect name="select" (change)="change(myselect)">`  you ask about `item.value` -make a `console.log(item)` to see what are you receiving-

Comment: forget my comment, I don't know about your app-bootstrap-dropdown

Comment: it is custom component to handle dynamic creation.. seems to be working... it gives me the values.. I am able to set in controller.. the drop down has like 10 values.. there are just 2 that don't work all other work .. which got me confused :/

Answer (score 0):

m    *If we declare the form group like this :
loginForm = new FormGroup({
WhateverKeyIS: new FormControl(null),
});

```
IN the method where we need to set the value:

patchValues(){
    this.loginForm.controls['WhateverKeyIS'].setValue('B10');
    console.log(this.loginForm.value,"values")
}

The above console is printed with the value which is set.Let me know if you are doing in different way?*
```

Comment: I am doing it the above way, I have updated my code with declaration and method for further understanding.

Comment: can you add your select code in html as well?